# Division and remainder algorithm in NTL

Tags: algorithm, ntl

I try to find or learn what a division algorithm use NTL(Number Theory Library), and complexity of this algorithm. (need algorithms in GF2X module and ZZ)
The implementation of these functions is a lot of code that is difficult to understand what is going in the algorithm.

Has anyone uses NTL? Maybe someone knows standart division and remainder algorithms and their comlexity from number theory and can help?

I can copy-paste listing of some functions.

Comment: What functions do you mean exactly? If you mean *everything that has to do with division*, your question is far too broad.

Comment: For example, GF2X lib, rem(GF2X& r, const GF2X& a, const GF2X& b)

This func in my case uses 
void PlainRem(GF2X& r, const GF2X& a, const GF2X& b) 

The name may be a clue, but very difficult to understand, and the implementation is difficult to calculate its complexity

Comment: looks like this would be quite a bit of work. I think this can only be done step by step and it will take some hours. Since I don't know the answer yet, I hope someone else will see this.